# Issue with copy link function within a SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, access-denied

Recently, a document library has inherited permissions from the parent site and contains files which store links to other locations within that library, mostly in PDF format.

There seems to be a bizarre issue with these links, however, as they no longer work.

When a link is clicked to another document, it begins with:

```
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/intranet/IMS/EbJY02HSAflPuJUuVCs98VABB-7-DCai5_21x_wRrGwWIA?e=KV7JxI
```

However it changes to this:

```
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/IMS/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?e=KV7JxI&share=EbJY02HSAflPuJUuVCs98VABB-7-DCai5_21x_wRrGwWIA
```

which throws this error:

[image: Error when clicking link]

However, I have read on here, that when the "guestaccess" text is changed to "download" the file then downloads as per normal.

So the link isn't broken per se, it just doesn't open correctly in the first instance.

Anyone out there seen this happen before? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have go through this [web](https://www.addictivetips.com/web/how-to-get-a-direct-download-link-for-a-file-in-office-365-document/) and maybe replace the "guesstaccess.aspx" to "download.aspx" is set as a workaround . You can also try the workaround [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2990807/sorry-you-cannot-access-this-document-error-when-a-guest-link-is-used) :

**Publish the affected document.**

**Change the Draft Item Security setting to Any user who can read items for the affected library.**

Or you can submit a support request to MS , may be they can find something in ULS log .

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I gave the publish feature ago but the issue still persists. I've contacted Microsoft with regard to viewing the ULS logs. If a fix is identified, will post here.

Comment: Not an answer per se, but a full site collection restore fixed the problem.